# Implement the below code in JNI?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I can get Services names linked with the below code in Java in android.

```
//packageToCheck - pass the package name
PackageInfo servicePackage = null;
servicePackage = pm.getPackageInfo(packageToCheck, PackageManager.GET_SERVICES);
ServiceInfo[] sinfo = servicePackage.services;

for(ServiceInfo Servinfo : sinfo){
  System.out.println("Service Name:" + Servinfo.name + "for Package:" + packageToCheck);
}
```

Now, I am trying to implement in JNI using C code. Any insight or sample code on how this can be implemented? Thanks!!!

My first attempt is:jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "1\n");
jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "getPackageManager", "()Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;");
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "2\n");
jobject packageManager = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, obj, mid);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "3\n");
// this.getPackageName()
mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "getPackageName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "4\n");
jstring packageName = (jstring) (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, obj, mid);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "5\n");
```

Just hangs in LogCat after outputting "2" . Not sure what's wrong!!!

Comment: For what purpose? And where is your first attempt?

Comment: Your first attempt bears no resemblance to the Java code you are trying to reimplement in JNI, and you still haven't given any *reason* for wanting to do so. I cannot see the point.

Comment: For matter of purpose, i have a same task and looking for solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really minimal example, you can check it out and run it.

https://bitbucket.org/sentimental/jni_poc

Comment: Bryan, this is a very simple example for JNI. However, I would be happy to get any implementations for my first attempt. Thanks!!!

Comment: @user1416662 Forget it. This isn't a free coding service. What you will get is a critique of *your* code.

Answer (score 0):

You can check another easy example in [here](http://patriot.net/~tvalesky/jninative.html)